# float ломает вёрстку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь воссоздать [этот](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_streetart.htm) пример с w3schools. Пытаюсь сделать верхнюю панель. Получается хорошо. Последний штрих - перенести одну из кнопок в правую часть панели. Использую для этого `float: left`. И вдруг кнопка приобретает огромный `height` и ломает всю вёрстку. Стоит отметить, что после удаления `line-height: 100px` (равный `height: 100px`) всё чинится. Но я не могу убрать эту строку, потому что с помощью неё я выравниваю кнопки по вертикали.

Как можно выйти из ситуации и почему она возникла? 
Стоит отметить, что у меня в браузере кнопка [сломала](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHJHS.jpg) так же расположение картинок, чего не наблюдается при запуске кода здесь.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif
}

.gallery {
    line-height: 0;
}

.gallery .side {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px;
    /*THERE*/
    line-height: 100px;
}

header a {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}

header a:last-child {
    /*AND THERE*/
    float: right;
}

header a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="">MY ART</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
    </header>
    
    <div class='gallery'>
         <div class="side">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/streetart.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/streetart2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/streetart5.jpg" alt="">
        </div
        ><div class="side">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/streetart3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/streetart4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>About</h1>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/boy.jpg" alt="" class="me">
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что если поместить этот `<a>` в `<div>` и применить `float: right` уже к этому `div`, почему-то кнопка приобретает именно те размеры, которые и должна. Но вёрстка картинок всё равно сломана.

Comment: Воспользовался `clearfix` (добавил между `header` и картинками `<div>` с `style='clear: both'`). Проблема с ломанием вёрстки картинок исправилась. Всё ещё непонятно, почему эти проблемы были. И всё ещё непонятно, почему применение `float: right` к `a` меняет вёрстку, а применение к `div` с `a` внутри - нет.

Comment: Ещё одна причина после завершения практики никогда не использовать `float`. Думаю, переписывание этого же макета с использованием `flexbox` или `grid` будет намного проще. Но нужно написать всеми способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй div с классом clearfix (Так принято).

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Он запрещает обтекание элемента по сторонам. 
А лучше не использовать float :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Но чем всё же обсуловлено такое странное изменение размера элемента? Я помню у меня из-за `clear` что-то просто пропадало, но такого ещё не было..

Comment: Конечно, я понимаю, что float использовать не стоит. Просто хочу набить руку, и сделать несколько разных макетов поочерёдно с помощью `float`, `flexbox` и `css grid`. Ведь хочешь-не хочешь, а контактировать с `float`-вёрсткой придётся.

Comment: Такое поведение появляется из-за обтекания, и он пытается обтекать его полностью по вертикали.

Comment: Ну это хорошо, просто видел как некоторые люди действительно полагали на будущее float)